# Clarification regarding Kubo formula and fluctuation-dissipation theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, fluctuation-dissipation

In the Wikipedia article for Fluctuation-dissipation theorem, under the [section for the derivation in the quantum case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem#Quantum_version), the Kubo formula is quoted.
\begin{align*}
\chi(t-t') = \frac{i}{\hbar} \theta(t - t') \langle [x(t), x(t')] \rangle
\end{align*}

However, on the [Wikipedia page on Kubo formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubo_formula), the Kubo formula is given by
\begin{align*}
\langle A(t) \rangle = \langle A \rangle_0 - i \int_{t_0}^{t} dt' \langle [A(t), V(t')] \rangle_0
\end{align*}

In the first expression, the RHS is the expectation of the commutator of $x$ evaluated at different times. In the second expression, there are two different operators in the commutator. If I set $t_0 = -\infty$, then the second equation is

\begin{align*}
\langle A(t) \rangle = \langle A \rangle_0 - i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt' \theta(t-t') \langle [A(t), V(t')] \rangle_0
\end{align*}

I also see the following equation in the Wikipedia page
\begin{align*}
\langle x(t) \rangle = \langle x \rangle_0 + \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(\tau) \chi(t - \tau) d \tau 
\end{align*}

Should I conclude that the first equation is a special case of the second equation with $A = V$? Otherwise, how are the two equations related?